# JavaScript cssText not working as expected in Firefox and Opera browsers

Tags: javascript, css

Please consider the code snippet below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">Sample Text</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var md=document.getElementById("mydiv");
md.style.cssText="background-color:yellow !important;color:red;font-size:70px;font-weight:bold;";
setTimeout(function(){
md.style.backgroundColor="blue";
md.innerHTML+="<br/>Updated!";
},2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Explanation: I am trying out the cssText browser support and noticed that cssText is not working as per my expectation in Firefox, Opera browsers.

The above code defines "background-color:yellow !important" and after 2 seconds the background-color is changed to blue. But since I have specified '!important' in my cssText, I assume the background-color should not get updated. This works in IE, Chrome, Safari. But not in Firefox, Opera.

Can someone please suggest.

EDIT: I want to specify the !important rule for a css property and restrict further changes to it via javascript. I would like to achieve this using JavaScript i.e. specifying !important via JavaScript. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not edit other people's answers with your own comments! Leave a comment saying what you think is incorrect, and if it is **very** _very_ bad and you strongly believe it should be removed by a moderator, flag it. However, IMHO I don't think you should do it for the answer below as it is a sincere attempt at helping you. Leaving comments is the _correct_ way to handle an answer that's not completely correct (IMO). If you look through other questions on this site, most have more than one answer, (at least if no answer is accepted). Please try with a bit more patience. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled across this question while googling for something else.

The first thing to understand, is that cssText doesn't create another style: It is merely a shorthand that lets you assign multiple styles at once. The following are roughly identical:

```
element.style.cssText = "background-color:yellow;color:red;";

element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
element.style.color = "red";
```

The only real thing to note, is that I believe that assigning to cssText will overwrite any existing element styles. Eg, the following will result in a style that is exactly equal to `color:red;` and *not* equal to `background-color:yellow;color:red;`. cssText effectively removes any existing element styles before applying the ones specified:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
element.style.cssText = "color:red;";
```

The second thing to realize, is that `!important` doesn't make a style read-only. It only prevents defined styles of higher specificities being used, and only does so as long as it is defined. When you assign the background color value of `blue`, you are effectively *removing* `!important` from the declaration. You'd have to set your background color as `background-color:blue !important;` in order to keep it.

In short, if something overwrites your `background-color:yellow !important;` with `background-color:blue;`, there's nothing you can do about it. Unless you do some other fancy work, like creating a timer interval that every X milliseconds resets the `yellow !important` style. But then you run into problems of having to keep track of the interval, especially if you *may* actually want to set the background color to some other value, otherwise it will just get overwritten on you!

```
var element = ...;
setInterval(1000, function(){
  if (element.style.backgroundColor != "yellow !important") {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow !important";
  }
});
```

The one thing I can think of, is if these styles are set in stone, you could just make them actual rules instead of inline element styles. You *can* keep the !important tag if you make it a rule:

```
.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

element.className = "bg-yellow";
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your JS modified code. I've checked in FF 27 and it is working.

```
var md=document.getElementById("mydiv");
md.style.cssText="background-color:yellow !important;color:red;font-size:70px;font-weight:bold;";
setTimeout(function(){
  md.style.setProperty="background-Color:blue"; //modified this line
md.innerHTML+="<br/>Updated!";
},2000);
```

Here is the Working Demo for you.
http://jsbin.com/kifozeka/2/edit

Comment: But, my problem is that once I declare !important for a property on a div, I want to ensure that it does not get overridden with some other script on the page, i.e. once I use cssText for specifying !important, then other script should not update the property style.

normally, most of the js code in the page is like mydiv.style.color="orange"; I cannot change the existing code to use mydiv.style.property="color:orange";

Comment: I have noticed that in Firefox, Opera when you use javascript for updating styles, then whatever you do using style object takes precedence than what was declared with cssText property

Comment: noticed that the code does not work, actually when you use md.style.property, it does not update any thing.
I tried to do my.style.property="color: green"; and it did not work.

There does not seem to be any valid mechanism to update style using ".property".

Comment: @Ashish I missed that and already updated the line..
it should be like this.
which firefox version you are using? I've checked in FF 27 and it was working.

Comment: there is nothing called setProperty
It is invalid
just try to update any other property on the div, for example 
md.style.setProperty="font-size:bold"; you will notice that it will not work.